# ReactJS + Material-UI: How to alternate colors between Material-UI <Table/>'s <TableRow/>?

Tags: javascript, html, css, reactjs, material-ui

I currently have a Material-UI's `<Table/>` ( http://www.material-ui.com/#/components/table ), and would like each row to switch off between color blue and purple. So first one would be blue, then next row would be purple, and so on for any additional row added.

How can I dynamically switch off between two colors for any additional rows added?

```
render(){

    return(
        <Table
          multiSelectable={true}
        >
          <TableHeader>
            <TableRow>
              <TableHeaderColumn>First Name</TableHeaderColumn>
              <TableHeaderColumn>Last Name</TableHeaderColumn>
              <TableHeaderColumn>Color</TableHeaderColumn>
            </TableRow>
          </TableHeader>
          <TableBody
            displayRowCheckbox={true}
            stripedRows
          >
              <TableRow>
                <TableRowColumn>John</TableRowColumn>
                <TableRowColumn>Smith</TableRowColumn>
                <TableRowColumn>Red</TableRowColumn>
              </TableRow>
              <TableRow>
                <TableRowColumn>Paul</TableRowColumn>
                <TableRowColumn>Row</TableRowColumn>
                <TableRowColumn>Black</TableRowColumn>
              </TableRow>
              <TableRow>
                <TableRowColumn>Doe</TableRowColumn>
                <TableRowColumn>Boe</TableRowColumn>
                <TableRowColumn>Pink</TableRowColumn>
              </TableRow>
              <TableRow>
                <TableRowColumn>Frank</TableRowColumn>
                <TableRowColumn>Done</TableRowColumn>
                <TableRowColumn>White</TableRowColumn>
              </TableRow>
              <TableRow>
                <TableRowColumn>Lucy</TableRowColumn>
                <TableRowColumn>Ju</TableRowColumn>
                <TableRowColumn>Orange</TableRowColumn>
              </TableRow>
          </TableBody>
        </Table>
```

Thank you in advance

Comment: https://github.com/callemall/material-ui#customization

Answer (score 20):

You can create a styled [TableRow](https://material-ui.com/api/table-row/) and apply the [even and odd css rules](https://www.w3.org/Style/Examples/007/evenodd.en.html).

---

### Material UI Version 5 (Styled Components)

```
const StyledTableRow = styled(TableRow)(({ theme }) => ({
  '&:nth-of-type(odd)': {
    backgroundColor: "white",
  },
  '&:nth-of-type(even)': {
    backgroundColor: "grey",
  },
}));
```

or

```
const StyledTableRow = styled(TableRow)`
  &:nth-of-type(odd) {
    background-color: ${({ theme }) => theme.palette.action.hover}; // accessing the theme
  }
  &:nth-of-type(even) {
    background-color: "grey";
  }
`;
```

###### (works both in Typescript and javascript)

---

### Material UI Version 4 (JSS)

using **Typescript:**

```
const StyledTableRow = withStyles((theme: Theme) =>
  createStyles({
    root: {
      '&:nth-of-type(odd)': {
        backgroundColor: "white",
      },
      '&:nth-of-type(even)': {
        backgroundColor: "grey",
      },
    },
  }),
)(TableRow);
```

using **Javascript:**

```
const StyledTableRow = withStyles((theme) => ({
  root: {
    '&:nth-of-type(odd)': {
      backgroundColor: "white",
    },
    '&:nth-of-type(even)': {
      backgroundColor: "grey",
    },
  },
}))(TableRow);
```

---

And using your example, this is how it should be:

```
render(){
  return(
    <Table multiSelectable={true} >
      <TableHeader>
        <TableRow>
          ...
        </TableRow>
      </TableHeader>
      <TableBody displayRowCheckbox={true} >
        <StyledTableRow>
          ...
        </StyledTableRow>
...
```

###### (stripedRows is no longer available in the newer versions of MUI, see other anwsers for that solution)

---

This is how Material-UI does their odd/even row style in their [docs](https://material-ui.com/components/tables/#customization).

You can see this working in the following examples:

- **[Material UI Version 4](https://codesandbox.io/s/suq42)**
- **[Material UI Version 5](https://codesandbox.io/s/p86020?file=/demo.tsx)**

Comment: This is the right answer. Give this man the ten thousand dollars

Comment: is there a Styled components solution also? I put up a bounty

Comment: sure @mattsmith5, Material Ui as updated their docs to to work with styled, give me a couple of minutes and i will put up a solution

Comment: @mattsmith5 done! hope it can help you

Answer (score 13):

Try this. This is working fine in @version 4.4.2

```
{
this.state.data.map((row,index)=> (
 <TableRow style ={ index % 2? { background : "#fdffe0" }:{ background : "white" }}> 
...
</TableRow>
))}
```

Hope this will help you. Happy Coding...!

Answer (score 6):

I'm a bit late, but for some reason `stripedRows` didn't work for me, which is why i did it that way:

Just use the modulo operator to switch between 2 colors

```
{this.state.data.map((row)=> (
 <TableRow style ={ row.rank % 2? { background : "#fdffe0" }:{ background : "white" }}> 
...
</TableRow>
))}
```

@Version 4.2.1

Answer (score 4):

You can use `stripedRows` prop for `<TableBody>` component to make the visual separation of rows, but I'm not sure that you can customise colors for this option.

```
<TableBody stripedRows > </TableBody>
```

Or you can achieve it by setting a `className` for `<TableBody>` component, and set colors with css [even and odd rules](https://www.w3.org/Style/Examples/007/evenodd.en.html). Probably, you should also set `!important` for those rules to override inline styles.

Comment: Before I accept the answer and upvote, do you know if it's possible to change the color with `stripedRows`? Because that is the best approach and tried searching for it but no luck on the customization...

Comment: I didn't found a way to do this. You can try customise theme, but I don't think that's the case, since color will be changed everywhere. I've also opened an issue on github, to discuss this situation with maintainers. You cant track it down, because I might be wrong and there is a solution. https://github.com/callemall/material-ui/issues/5286

Comment: Thank you so much! Will keep an eye out. One last question, upon selecting a checkbox, is there a way to get rid of the row highlight?

Comment: Not sure I've understood you correctly. Do you mean to cancel striped property for all the rows or just for one?

Comment: http://www.material-ui.com/#/components/table here in second example you can toggle `stripedRows` prop for the table. Might be helpful example.

Comment: No worries. When I click the checkbox and check it off, the row gets highlighted. Was wondering how to get rid of the highlight even if I checked off the checkbox.

Comment: What checkbox are you talking about?:) I don't see any checkboxes in the code sample you've provided.

Comment: `displayRowCheckbox` for the TableBody. Just forgot to include it :D

Comment: please let me know if you've seen my last comment.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/124602/discussion-between-lazarev-alexandr-and-ly-maneug).

Comment: Sometime between 2016 and 2019, this has changed and "stripedRows" is no longer available. Instead, you can do something similar:

`{rows.map((row, index) => (
    <TableRow key={row.percent} className={index%2 ? classes.lightRow : classes.darkRow}>
))}`

Answer (score 2):

> Looking for alternative solution using React Styled Components as similar to this

The best way if you are using Material UI is to select **@emotion** instead of **styled-component**. They are both  similar, but in Material UI documentation has some caveat if we will want to use **styled-components**. Therefore, I prefer using **@emotion** with Material UI to avoid some problems in the future.

> ❗ Warning: Using styled-components as an engine at this moment is not working when used in a SSR projects. The reason is that the babel-plugin-styled-components is not picking up correctly the usages of the styled() utility inside the @mui packages. For more details, take a look at this issue. We strongly recommend using emotion for SSR projects. [Material UI](https://mui.com/material-ui/guides/styled-engine/#how-to-switch-to-styled-components)

The second reason: Material UI is using **@emotion** as a styling engine by default.

For the solution I will use Material UI v5.9.2 and  many of the previous component in this question are invalid. We need to replace old components and then use **@emotion** to add an extra pseudo-class to the **TableRow** component. Also, we will override `td` color property inside the **TableRow** to keep everything in one component.

```js
import Table from "@mui/material/Table";
import TableHead from "@mui/material/TableHead";
import TableBody from "@mui/material/TableBody";
import TableRow from "@mui/material/TableRow";
import TableCell from "@mui/material/TableCell";

import styled from "@emotion/styled";

const TableRowStyled = styled(TableRow)`
  &:nth-of-type(odd) {
    background-color: blue;
  }
  &:nth-of-type(even) {
    background-color: purple;
  }
  & > td {
    color: white;
  }
`;

export default function App() {
  return (
    <div className="App">
      <Table>
        <TableHead>
          <TableRow>
            <TableCell>First Name</TableCell>
            <TableCell>Last Name</TableCell>
            <TableCell>Color</TableCell>
          </TableRow>
        </TableHead>
        <TableBody>
          <TableRowStyled>
            <TableCell>John</TableCell>
            <TableCell>Smith</TableCell>
            <TableCell>Red</TableCell>
          </TableRowStyled>
          <TableRowStyled>
            <TableCell>Paul</TableCell>
            <TableCell>Row</TableCell>
            <TableCell>Black</TableCell>
          </TableRowStyled>
          <TableRowStyled>
            <TableCell>Doe</TableCell>
            <TableCell>Boe</TableCell>
            <TableCell>Pink</TableCell>
          </TableRowStyled>
        </TableBody>
      </Table>
    </div>
  );
}
```

[image: Edit dazziling-code]